# Failed to find provider for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Tags: android

**I Am trying to use**:

```
public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath){
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    Timber.d("270");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    Timber.d("180");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    Timber.d("90");
                    break;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }
```

**I Am passing the URL:**

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181109_144042.jpg
```

**I am getting the error**:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider  for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
```

Comment: have you added read permission in manifest ?

Comment: What is the Read permission .. because i am not using custom content provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying that `imageUri` is `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181109_144042.jpg`, you should not be calling `context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);`. `notifyChange()` is:

- For use by `ContentProvider` implementations (which this is not), and
- Is for `content` `Uri` values (which this is not)

Comment: what should be called instead then?

Comment: @afhamu: Nothing. To be honest, I have no idea why the OP has that line in their original sample.